# POVRAY for windows: using the command line to render several pov files

Tags: windows, command-line, povray

I am trying to automate the rendering of several pov files so I made a simple
script that runs all the pov (pvengine.exe...etc) in a for loop.

However, this doesn't work since the GUI editor always comes up so that I have
to manually close it down before the next one can start. By looking on this
forum and google, there is apparently no way to shut the editor vai the command
line...(is that right?)

So, the only other way I thought about is to use the file queue in the editor.
Is there a way of using that feature from the command line ?

Cheers and many thanks in advance !
David

---

UPDATE:

I found this:
http://news.povray.org/povray.animations/message/%3C47324428%40news.povray.org%3E/#%3C47324428%40news.povray.org%3E
but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Command-Line Options](http://povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/603/) in the Windows documentation lists the `/EXIT` and `/RENDER` options that you need.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that the Windows contextual menu for the right-click has a "render and exit" for pov files so I looked at the command it launches for that which is:

```
pvengine.exe /EXIT /RENDER "%1"
```

where %1 is the file being rendered.